# python assign build-in property function to list element

Tags: python

I don't understand why the following code gives two different outputs

```
class foo(object):

       def myget(self):
          return 3

       goo=property(myget)

       hh1=[1,2,3]
       hh1[0]=property(myget)

       def hh(self):
         print self.goo
         print self.hh1[0]
ff=foo()
ff.hh()
```

---

output:

```
 3
 <property object at 0x292a998>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think it may be related to **dict**.  descriptor (property) only respond to attributes inside object or class **dict**. Both hh1[] and goo are in foo.**dict**. but hh1[0] is not, therefore, descriptor doesnt work in hh1[0].

Answer (score 1):

`property` objects are [descriptors](http://docs.python.org/howto/descriptor.html).  Descriptors only have special powers when bound to a class.  Otherwise, they behave exactly like any other class.  When you put the property in a list, it is not bound to the class, so it loses it's special properties.

---

For an example, let's look at an implementation of `property` [written in pure python](http://docs.python.org/howto/descriptor.html#properties) as descriptors:

```
class Property(object):
    "Emulate PyProperty_Type() in Objects/descrobject.c"

    def __init__(self, fget=None, fset=None, fdel=None, doc=None):
        self.fget = fget
        self.fset = fset
        self.fdel = fdel
        self.__doc__ = doc

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):
        if obj is None:
            return self
        if self.fget is None:
            raise AttributeError, "unreadable attribute"
        return self.fget(obj)

    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        if self.fset is None:
            raise AttributeError, "can't set attribute"
        self.fset(obj, value)

    def __delete__(self, obj):
        if self.fdel is None:
            raise AttributeError, "can't delete attribute"
        self.fdel(obj)
```

Notice how the second argument to `__get__`, `__set__` and `__delete__` are obj?  `obj` is the instance of the class that the descriptor is bound to (it gets passed to the method as `self` if that help clarify things).  In order for the whole shebang to work, the descriptor must be bound to a class so that `__get__` can be called and `obj` can be passed to it.  If the descriptor isn't bound to a class, then `__get__` doesn't get called and your descriptor class becomes just another class with a couple of magic methods that never get called (unless you call them explicitly).

Maybe slightly more concretely, when you do:

```
a = instance.my_descriptor
```

this calls `my_descriptor.__get__(instance)` and correspondingly:

```
instance.my_descriptor = a
```

calls `my_descriptor.__set__(instance,a)`

However, if `my_descriptor` isn't bound to a class, then it behaves just like any other class (object) which explains what you're seeing.

Comment: "When you put the property in a list, it is not bound to the class" why list doesnt bound to the class??

Comment: @fcai -- the list is an attribute of the class, however, when you put the object in the list, it's very different than putting the object on the class directly.  See my update.  Hopefully that will help de-mystify it a bit.  Specifically, for the property in the list, how is it supposed to know what `instance` should be passed to `__get__` or `__set__`?

Comment: thanks.  i know everything is object in python, right?   a list is an object. is a list's element hh[0] an object as well?  can we pass hh[0] as an instance?

Comment: `hh[0]` is (probably) an instance of something.  (I say probably because it could be a `class` or a `module`, etc ...), but it's definitely an object.  In your case, it is an instance of a `property`.  But it is too far removed from the instance of the class `foo` to know anything about that instance (or even the class `foo` for that mattter).  The only thing `hh[0]` knows about is itself.